# Django MongoDB Embedded Models

Tags: django, mongodb, django-models

When I create a class/model specifically for the purposes of being embedded into another class/model, a collection is still written for the former in my mongodb database. The aforementioned does not cause any trouble other than the inconvenience of being there, but I'm still wondering if there is any way for a collection not to be written?

Answer (score 0):

I have a nonrel django project as well. Its just a thing django does (and that the nonrel fork  has not specifically addressed), that when you define a model that is not abstract or proxy, it is going to generate a collection (table) during a syncdb. Whether you save anything to that collection is further dependent on your code obviously.

If there is some trick to having a concrete model not create a collection in nonrel django, then I am missing something as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible if you use `abstract=True` for that model.

However, you can't use lazy lookup (aka `EmbeddedModelField('SomeModelThatsNotYetDefined')` yet (https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangotoolbox/issues/15).